# Laravel and Eloquent : Filter to get only a sub key of json in response

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a mysql table (5.7.1) called "inventory" with 2 columns :

- id {String}
- inventory {json}

inventory column contains a json as following for example:

```
{
    id : "212",
    inventory : {
        data : {
            id : "3",
            demo : true,
            access : false
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get in response the following json :

```
data : {
    id : "3",
    demo : true,
    access : false
}
```

For the moment, i use the following method :

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('id', "212")->first();
return response()->json($inventory);
```

This code allows to get the entire content of the entry in table which have id = 212.

But how can i do to only get the content of a subKey of json of "inventory" column in response by making a single request to database ?

Comment: I 've red through the docs that you could update json column using [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#updating-json-columns) syntax so what i suggest is to try to use this syntax for example `return response()->json($inventory->inventory->inventory);`  if That does not work you can decode your `$inventory->inventory` json and just get the key you want

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Inventory` model

```
protected $casts = [
    'inventory' => 'array'
];
```

Then do this in your controller

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('id', "212")->first();
return response()->json($inventory->inventory);
```

Edit : Access them as an array to get the individual items.

```
$inventory->inventory['data']
$inventory->inventory['data']['demo']
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i do to retrieve only a subKey of the json. For example the key 'demo' in my json example ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos updated my answer. you can access them as array items since we're casting the json data to an array.

Comment: Ok, and do you know if it's possible to filter directly in the request : where('id', "212")-> .....

Comment: @wawanopoulos you can with no issues. add condition like so `->where('inventory->data', 3)`. Check this if you want examples https://mattstauffer.co/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: In fact, i have 2 things to do in the request : a first filter with the column 'mimId'. And then, get only the content of the subkey data in ths entire json present in inventory column. How can i do that ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos i don't see the column `mimId` in your question in the table or data. It's 2am here so i'll be off. It's stackoverflow's policy to keep each question related to one thing. You can mark this as answered and post a relevant question for the further query you have. If not me then someone else will help you. If no one has by the morning, i'll come back and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try $inventory->pluck('inventory').

Comment: You can always follow up with some explanation behind the code snippets. What is `pluck`, etc...